# Wait for ajax element to complete (.Net Web browser control)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

How can i wait for page inner element to complete ?

Tried:

- `while (webBrowser.IsBusy)`
- `while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)`
- creating delegate for `webBrowser_DocumentCompleted`
  but they all for the full page / url and not inner content.

how can i wait for inner elements of the page to complete?

(that elements did't have names / id's)

Comment: `DocumentCompleted` is for the entire document and its content indeed. There is no method in between.

Comment: Sometimes there is java code running that you can't detect with a webbrowser.  In these cases I usually have to check when contents changes from null to a valid value.

Comment: What do you mean by inner content? Do you have some iframes or is there any ajax request which starts after document ready?

Comment: the only way i see is to search for expected element

Comment: @Reza Aghaei - ajax request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In server-side code, you cannot make sure when the inner content will be ready or loaded. You have to use client-side scripts to decide on that. If you only want to wait for document fully loaded, you can use Jquery document ready function like;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // do something
});
```